# Video broadcasting application for OS X

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, streaming, encoding

I need tips on a good application that you can stream "live" video and publish that on a website.

The source is raw video from a video mixer and i will have my os x machine in the middle and then out to one of my webservers.

Answer (score 2):

Would [UStream](http://www.ustream.tv) be what you are looking for?

Ustream is a free service (with a paid upgrade) for streaming from any platform to any platform. Users can view the video stream online or via a native app (iOS and Android). I highly recommend Ustream, as it works great and (best of all) is free. You can broadcast from the web interface:
[image: Ustream web broadcaster]

Or from [Ustream Producer](http://www.ustream.tv/producer) (free), which is a native app that runs on both OS X and Windows:

[image: Ustream Producer]

Ustream Producer has many features including:

- [Screencasting](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#Single)
- [Single camera broadcasting](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#Import)
- [Save broadcast to watch later](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#Record)
- [Importing movies, stills and music](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#Import)

There are two paid upgrades for Ustream Producer, Ustream Producer Pro ($199), or Ustream Producer Studio ($549).

Ustream Producer Pro includes all the features of the free Ustream Producer, but also adds:

- [HD broadcasting](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#HD)
- [Multiple camera angles](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#Multiple)
- [HDV camera support](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#HDV)
- [Titles, Layers, and Picture-in-pictures](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#Titles)

Ustream Producer Studio adds:

- [Chroma Keying](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#Chroma) (green or blue screen support)
- [Audio Sync Delay](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#Audio)
- [IP camera support](http://www.ustream.tv/producer#IP)

I highly recommend Ustream, as we use it for church and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) has a bunch of streaming options (and a lot of documentation on their website)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a video broadcast solution [here](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/extending/resources.html)

> .. With QuickTime Broadcaster, anyone can produce a live broadcast
>   event and anyone with an Internet connection can “virtually” attend.
>   The combination of QuickTime Broadcaster, QuickTime Streaming Server,
>   and QuickTime provides an end-to-end MPEG-4-based Internet
>   broadcasting system, allowing you to reach not only the large and
>   growing QuickTime Player base, but also any ISO-compliant MPEG-4
>   player.

Comment: no ustream is something you need their website for. i need something for my own webserver.

Comment: @norrfors You commented on the wrong answer. This answer doesn't reference UStream, daviesgeek's answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Flash Media Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/).

I'm not sure what you're using on the website for streaming server, I've been using [Red5](http://www.red5.org), the OSS version of Flash Media Server, for browser side webcam video capture. It can also do live streaming and video conferencing but I haven't tried.

I would recommend QTSS but far more browsers have Flash installed then they do quicktime.

Video streaming isn't the easiest thing in the world to get right so I wish you good luck.